# Android material L image transition interpolator

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

This is more of a mathematics question rather than programming.

Well, I would like to ask id you know what is the interpolator described in Material design:

[image]

It looks to be an `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator` but the deceleration effect decays slower.

My best hatch is :

```
public class MaterialInterpolator implements Interpolator {

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        if(input<1./3f)
            return new AccelerateInterpolator().getInterpolation(input);
        else
            return new DecelerateInterpolator().getInterpolation(input);
    }

}
```

Which creates a gap between the values:

```
Time / Value
...
0.3,0.09
0.317,0.100489
0.333,0.110889  <-- gap
0.35,0.57750005
0.367,0.599311
0.383,0.61931103
0.4,0.64
...
```

---

Decelerating the AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator:

```
output = accelerateDecelerateInterpolator(decelerateInterpolator(input));

private float accelerateDecelerateInterpolator(float input) {
    return (float)(Math.cos((input + 1) * Math.PI) / 2.0f) + 0.5f;
}

private float decelerateInterpolator(float input) {
    //  return 1.0f - (1.0f - input) * (1.0f - input);
    return  (float)(1.0f - Math.pow((1.0f - input), 2 * mFactor));  // default factor =1.f
}
```

Gives rates similar to:

[image]

And value/time curve:

[image]

<s>not sure if at the beginning is an output error or the actual behavior</s> should be an output error

---

Source: http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/imagery-treatment.html

Comment: at the end (time == 1) the value is 0?

Comment: @pskink Nope it's `1.0f` ( `new DecelerateInterpolator().getInterpolation( 1f)` gives 1f). I assume the graph above shows the rate per time (frame@x time minus frame@x-1 time) of the animation and not the values per time of e.g. the saturation

Comment: ok so in pseudocode this should look like:  
AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.getInterpolation(DecelerateInterpolator.getInterpolation(input))

Comment: @pskink So "decelerate" the A/D interpolator? Tried it, it might not be the answer not the answer but very close. Either way there are no numbers on Google's example to be sure. Added a screenshot with the rates above

Comment: yes,  extend AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator and in getInterpolation call input = di.getInterpolation(input) then call super,  where di is a DecelerateInterpolator object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The support library now has interpolators for pre-Lollipop devices: FastOutLinearInInterpolator, **FastOutSlowInInterpolator**, LinearOutSlowInInterpolator, and PathInterpolatorCompat.

Docs: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/animation/package-summary.html

Source: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/animation

Answer (score 5):

Those plots look very much like plots of `x*(a*x+b)^2`.
With restrictions on the second root being equal to 1, it's like `a*x*(x-1)^2`.
Integrated it, chose `a` so that the result is 1 at `x=1` and got `3*x^4-8*x^3+6*x^2`.

The code would be:

```
public class MaterialInterpolator implements Interpolator {

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float x) {
        return (float) (6 * Math.pow(x, 2) - 8 * Math.pow(x, 3) + 3 * Math.pow(x, 4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 5 now provides interpolators for the three basic curves in the material design specification:

```
 * @android:interpolator/fast_out_linear_in
 * @android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in
 * @android:interpolator/linear_out_slow_in
```

You most likely want the `fast_out_slow_in` interpolator.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the source for the `fast_out_slow_in.xml` interpolator [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/232b0ad83439b1e0be49e1e149429af387dca24e/core/res/res/interpolator/fast_out_slow_in.xml) if you want to use them on Android pre 5.0.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pathInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:controlX1="0.4"
    android:controlY1="0"
    android:controlX2="0.2"
    android:controlY2="1"/>`

Comment: Paths only exist on 5.0 or later.