# Translate (curve path) + Scale animation Android

Tags: android

[image]

I want to translate a imageview in a curve while scaling it as it translates.

Ive gone through
Multiple posts like
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30254927/3518278
where i cant figure out how to compute my path variable

also
its mentioned here that android 5 provides basic curves in interpolars
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26591870/3518278
but they seem to have no effect.

My current code is

```
View view;
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1); // values from 0 to 1
        animator.setDuration(5000); // 5 seconds duration from 0 to 1
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()))
                        .floatValue();
                // Set translation of your view here. Position can be calculated
                // out of value. This code should move the view in a half circle.
                img_fullscreen_drone.setTranslationX((float)(150.0 * Math.sin(value*Math.PI)));
                img_fullscreen_drone.setTranslationY((float)(150.0 * Math.cos(value*Math.PI)));
                img_fullscreen_drone.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                img_fullscreen_drone.animate().scaleX(0.5f).scaleY(0.5f).setDuration(5000).start();

            }
        });

        animator.start();
```

this translates my view in a arc but after translation is complete scale starts,i want scale and translate along curve to happen toghether.

Any help will be appreicated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your original code was restarting the scale animation every frame of the animation that translated the image. You just need to move the scale animation code out of the update block, as below.

Note that your using two slightly different methods of animation, for scale vs. translate, which is perhaps what confused you.

```
    View view;
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1); // values from 0 to 1
    animator.setDuration(5000); // 5 seconds duration from 0 to 1
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()))
                    .floatValue();
            // Set translation of your view here. Position can be calculated
            // out of value. This code should move the view in a half circle.
            img_fullscreen_drone.setTranslationX((float)(150.0 * Math.sin(value*Math.PI)));
            img_fullscreen_drone.setTranslationY((float)(150.0 * Math.cos(value*Math.PI)));
        }
    });

    animator.start();

    img_fullscreen_drone.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    img_fullscreen_drone.animate().scaleX(0.5f).scaleY(0.5f).setDuration(5000).start();
```

Comment: 150 was an arbitrary value used by the original poster.

Comment: when I click on it, it takes it down and then up, how do I make it go the animation when the starting position is where it is right now

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling with Joel's answer, I found out you could also use a [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) and write it all at once this way:

```
img_fullscreen_drone.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
img_fullscreen_drone.animate()
  .setUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()));
        // Set translation of your view here. Position can be calculated
        // out of value. This code should move the view in a half circle.
        img_fullscreen_drone.setTranslationX((float)(150.0 * Math.sin(value*Math.PI)));
        img_fullscreen_drone.setTranslationY((float)(150.0 * Math.cos(value*Math.PI)));
    }})
  .scaleX(0f).scaleY(0f)
  .setDuration(5000)
  .start();
```

Not tested by I think it should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Make an animator set first. So something like

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
```

Then you have to separate your 2 animations which is translate and scale in form of an animator which you can do like

for translate use  :

```
ObjectAnimator translateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "y", toValue);
```

same you you can do for scale. Then you can do play together

```
set.playTogether(translateAnimator, scaleAnimator);
```

That should scale and translate together.